# Trying to anchor an image for iOS programming

Tags: ios, user-interface, anchor

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class PageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.backgroundColor = .yellow
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "page1")
        return iv
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .blue

        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.(topAnchor, bottomAnchor, rightAnchor, leftAnchor)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

When compiling this it shows this error. `Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'anchorToTop'` By the way I am trying to anchor an image to an individual UIImageViewCell.

Comment: In what language or API is it legal to say `imageView.(topAnchor, bottomAnchor, rightAnchor, leftAnchor)`? That is not a valid line of Swift, unless something has stepped in with an extension to change the language. If you are using such an extension, you need to tell us about it.

Comment: Oh sorry, probably a typo. These fingers type on their own.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
func setupViews() {

     backgroundColor = .blue
     imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     self.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
     imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0 ).isActive = true
     imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0 ).isActive = true
     imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 0 ).isActive = true
     imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 0 ).isActive = true
 }
```